# andengine load angled rectangle

Tags: box2d, andengine, trigonometry

I'm using AndEngine LevelLoader in Gles2 to load rectangles which form the walls for my game.

```
<entity x="0" y="477" width="800" height="10" type="wall"/>
<entity x="800" y="477" width="240" height="10" angle="315" type="wall"/>
```

And using the following code to create the rectangle

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y,
            width, height, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    rect.setRotation(angle); 
    Body block = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, rect,
            BodyType.StaticBody, objectFixtureDef);
```

It works, but what I want the image below demonstrates what happens. Is there any formulae for working out what Y value to start the rectangle at so it meets up, or how to transform the rectangle so that it starts next to the other one?

Thanks in advance. 
[image: Rotated rectangle level]

Comment: You are using GLES 2.0 Anchor Center?

Comment: No, not Anchor Center just the GLES 2 branch.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Entity` class, you have a function called `setRotationCenter`,
You can use it to change point where to rotate your entity. By default it is initialized to be at the center of the Entity.

use :

```
rect.setRotationCenter(0,0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I got the angled rectangle now floating some distance above the horizontal one Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y,
    width, height, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
  rect.setRotationCenter(0, 0);
  rect.setRotation(angle);

Comment: Also, setting the rotationCenter isn't also updating the body, so that things rebound off the rectangle's original position without the rotation.

Comment: My bad, sorry .. not specialist with the Box2D extension. This might help you? http://www.andengine.org/forums/post24493.html#p24493